# Id taken as file path for the template passed into ngDialog.open()

Tags: angularjs, ng-dialog

I am using `ngDialog.open()` to open a dialog. I want to pass in the template id to the function like this:

```
ngDialog.open({template: 'templateid'});
```

However, from the Network history, I find it is trying to fetch the `templateid` as a file on server.

I feel the `ngDialog.open()` function's interface design is a little confusing: The value of `template` options parameter can be either inline immediate HTML, or the file path of an HTML file on server, or the id of a `<script>` element. How should I distinguish them?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 options, not 3: either the filename for the template, or the template as a string. To provide the template as a string you set `plain: true` in the options to `open()`, so otherwise it will be interpreted as a filename.

The third option -- selecting the template by id -- is actually using a filename that is in Angular's `$templateCache`. If the name you provide is not in `$templateCache` for some reason, then it will be requested from the server.

One way to add a template to `$templateCache` is to use a `script` tag like this (example from Angular docs):

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="templateId.html">
  <p>This is the content of the template</p>
</script>
```

The main caveat here is that this must be somewhere inside the element that you have `ng-app` on.

The [`$templateCache`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$templateCache) docs also note that you can add a template in code by injecting `$templateCache` and calling `$templateCache.put()` and get one by calling `$templateCache.get()` which could be useful in debugging your situation.